# Permanent Code Folding in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I am trying to make sure that code collapsing in RStudio (through Alt+L) in a Shiny remains in place when I save the file. At present, every time I save my file, the folding disappears. Does anybody know how to make folding permanent and independent of saving the file?
For reference: I am using version 0.99.441 of RStudio on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Update, 8.17.15: I was informed that this is fixed in today's build. Check it out: https://dailies.rstudio.com

.................

Thanks for bringing this up. I have been experiencing this same disturbing behaviour for a couple of months now. I'm using version 0.99.467 on Windows 7 OS.

I have notified RStudio team of this behaviour, asking if it can be fixed or turned off (if this is some sort of feature). 
It may be worthwhile to fill out another request (by others experiencing this):
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Frankly, I think this is a bug, not a feature. No such behavior is explained on Code Folding and Sections page of RStudio website:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections

Comment: Thx, we will check it out.

Comment: You are welcome. So far it's stable for me. If it also works for you, please rate the answer :) Cheers! Oleg.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, Rstudio 99.1130 (newest available preview) and the code folding never saves for me. Also, I don't use projects and have my global options set to NOT restore anything from the previous session... and it always attempts to open my scripts and / or tables that were open when I quit RStudio the last time. Any tips?