# Rstudio - keeping code folded when run / file closed

Tags: r, rstudio

This question appears to be mentioned briefly here - [Permanent Code Folding in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997739/permanent-code-folding-in-rstudio) - however for windows and a bit outdated. I am on OS X with RStudio version 0.99.891.

I use command-alt-L to fold code in R-studio, and would prefer if the code remains folded when I both (1) save/close/reopen the file, and (2) run the folded code. Currently, doing both (1) and (2) unfolds the code, which is slightly frustrating.

Anyone know if this is avoidable, or something I should learn to live with?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to ask the RStudio team if you haven't. It does not appear to be a feature currently, but you could request it. I have also wanted this feature.

Comment: thanks, okay will do

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 5):

If you put `# ####` around every bit you want to fold and then when you open the script **Alt+O** (**Cmd+Option+O** on Mac) that will fold everything. Then highlighting the line and running it keeps it folded.

Comment: But how to unfold?